# How do I show that $\mu \wedge \nu \leq \mu, \nu$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm using Royden & Fitzpatrick for real analysis, and one of the problems defines (for signed measures $\mu$ and $\nu$) $\mu \wedge \nu = \frac{1}{2}(\mu + \nu - |\mu - \nu|)$ and $\mu \vee \nu = \mu + \nu - \mu \wedge \nu$, and requires us to show that $\mu \wedge \nu \leq \mu, \nu$ and that if $\eta$ is any other signed measure smaller than $\mu, \nu$, then $\eta \leq \mu \wedge \nu$. I've tried everything I can think of, but the best I've been able to come up with is $\mu \wedge \nu \leq |\nu|, |\mu|$ with the reverse triangle inequality. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: For $a,b\in\mathbb R$ you have $\tfrac 12(a+b-|a-b|) = \min(a,b)$.

Comment: What concerns me about that is that $\mu \wedge \nu$ is a signed measure, but in general, $\min\{\mu, \nu\}$ is not, because it fails to be countably additive. So I don't think we can force that equality.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be an element of the corresponding $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$. Then for any $\varepsilon > 0$ we find disjoint $A_1,\ldots,A_n\subset A$ in $\Sigma$ such that
$$
|\mu-\nu|(A) = \sum_{j=1}^n|\mu(A_j)-\nu(A_j)| + \varepsilon',
$$
where $\varepsilon'\le\varepsilon$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
(\mu\wedge\nu)(A)
&= \sum_{j=1}^n\big[\mu(A_j) + \nu(A_j) - |\mu(A_j)-\nu(A_j)|\big] - \varepsilon'\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n\min\{\mu(A_j),\nu(A_j)\} - \varepsilon'.
\end{align*}
From this everything follows.